# Bubbling Event from Child Component to the Grand Parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with the following structure:

```
App -> ProductList -> ProductItemRow
```

The App component is responsible for fetching all the products and then passing it to the ProductList to display. ProductList calls ProductItemRow for each product. ProductItemRow is responsible for displaying each single product on the screen.

The implementation is shown below (The complete app):

```
function ProductItemRow(props) {
  const product = props.product 

  return (
    <li>{product.title} <button onClick = {() => props.deleteProductItem(product)}>Delete</button></li>
  )
}

function ProductList(props) {

  const products = props.products 
  const productItems = products.map(product => {
    return <ProductItemRow key = {product.id} product = {product}
    deleteProductItem = {props.deleteProductItem}
    />
  })

  return (
      <>
      <h1>Product List</h1>
      {productItems}
      </>
  )
}

function App() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products')
    const products = await response.json() 
    return products 
  }

  const deleteProductItem = (product) => {
    console.log('FOO')
    console.log(product)
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    (async () => {
      const products = await fetchProducts() 
    setProducts(products)
    })() 

    
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <ProductList products = {products} deleteProductItem = {deleteProductItem} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I want to make my ProductList and ProductItemRow reusable so they don't delete the item. ProductItemRow uses a callback to send it up to the ProductList. The ProductList sends it up to the App component and that is where we can delete it.

As you can see that is quite a bit of callbacks to get it to the grand parent. I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this situation. I can use the global state  but using global state inside the ProductList and ProductItemRow will again make it less reusable component.

Any ideas?